# PITest cannot find tests

Tags: pitest

Our projects are all set up with a master parent for the entire company. For the project I'm working on, we have a root pom that references that parent with many modules underneath it. Attempting to use PITest with any one of these modules individually, or at the root module results in no test being run.

```
λ lp-server-write  mvn clean org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.company.platform.server:lp-server-write:jar:0.0.305-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ com.company.platform.server:lp-server-root:0.0.305-SNAPSHOT, /me/Documents/dev/code/server/pom.xml, line 69, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Platform Server :: App Write 0.0.305-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.company.thirdparty.generated.thing:thing-231:jar:2.3.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ lp-server-write ---
[INFO] Deleting /me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- pitest-maven:1.2.0:mutationCoverage (default-cli) @ lp-server-write ---
[INFO] Found plugin : Default csv report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Default xml report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Default html report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Default limit mutations plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Kotlin junk mutations filter
[INFO] Found shared classpath plugin : Default mutation engine
[INFO] Adding org.pitest:pitest to SUT classpath
[INFO] Mutating from /me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target/classes
4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : Running report with ReportOptions [targetClasses=[^com\.company\..*$], excludedMethods=[], excludedClasses=[^.*.*\..*IT$, ^.*.*\..*SpringBootTest$], codePaths=[/me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target/classes], reportDir=/me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target/pit-reports, historyInputLocation=null, historyOutputLocation=null, sourceDirs=[/me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/src/main/java, /me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/src/test/java], classPathElements=[/me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target/test-classes, /me/Documents/dev/code/server/lp-server-write/target/classes, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/common/lp-server-common-test/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-test-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/common/integrationtests/common-integrationtest/0.0.20/common-integrationtest-0.0.20.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/rest-assured/2.9.0/rest-assured-2.9.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/2.4.7/groovy-xml-2.4.7.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/json-path/2.9.0/json-path-2.9.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/2.4.7/groovy-json-2.4.7.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/rest-assured-common/2.9.0/rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/xml-path/2.9.0/xml-path-2.9.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.3.0/jsonassert-1.3.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/json-path-2.2.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.2.1/json-smart-2.2.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.5/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.5/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.8.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.8.5/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.8.5/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.12/lombok-1.16.12.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/decision/lp-server-decision-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-decision-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/common/lp-server-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/annotations/pt-annotation-processors/1.0.3/pt-annotation-processors-1.0.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/annotations/pt-annotations/1.0.3/pt-annotations-1.0.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/utils/lombok-test-robot/1.0.1/lombok-test-robot-1.0.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/datapublica/pg/hibernate-json/0.3/hibernate-json-0.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.8.5/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-kotlin/2.8.5/jackson-module-kotlin-2.8.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.0/kotlin-reflect-1.1.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics/0.6.4/jaxb2-basics-0.6.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-runtime/0.6.4/jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-tools/0.6.4/jaxb2-basics-tools-0.6.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/google/code/javaparser/javaparser/1.0.8/javaparser-1.0.8.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8/1.2.0-company/mapstruct-jdk8-1.2.0-company.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.2.0-company/mapstruct-processor-1.2.0-company.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar, /me/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/axonframework/axon-spring/3.0.2/axon-spring-3.0.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-money/0.11/joda-money-0.11.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1212.jre7/postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-hateoas-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.20.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.20.0.RELEASE.jar, /security/spring-security-core/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/lp-server-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar, /spring-test/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-test-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /spring-core/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar, /boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-test/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/read/lp-server-read/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-read-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/calculator/pt-lp-calculator-core/0.0.13/pt-lp-calculator-core-0.0.13.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/calculator/pt-lp-calculator-common/0.0.13/pt-lp-calculator-common-0.0.13.jar, /spring-context/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.6.1/springfox-swagger2-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.10/swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.10/swagger-models-1.5.10.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.6.1/springfox-spi-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.6.1/springfox-core-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.6.1/springfox-schema-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.6.1/springfox-swagger-common-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.6.1/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar, /plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, /plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.0.0.Final/mapstruct-1.0.0.Final.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.6/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.6/tomcat-juli-8.5.6.jar, /spring-jdbc/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.5.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar, /me/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, /jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, /enterprise/cdi-api/1.1/cdi-api-1.1.jar, /el/el-api/2.2/el-api-2.2.jar, /spec/javax/interceptor/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Beta1/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar, /annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar, /inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.5.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.5.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.5.4/byte-buddy-1.5.4.jar, /transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, /data/spring-data-jpa/1.10.6.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar, /data/spring-data-commons/1.12.6.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar, /spring-orm/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar, /spring-aspects/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /spring-aop/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /security/spring-security-config/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, /security/spring-security-web/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/axonframework/axon-test/3.0.2/axon-test-3.0.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/axonframework/axon-core/3.0.2/axon-core-3.0.2.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.9/xstream-1.4.9.jar, /me/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.4c/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar, /boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.6.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, /validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, /logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.5/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar, /spring-web/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /spring-beans/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /spring-webmvc/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /spring-expression/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/pt-lp-common/0.0.80/pt-lp-common-0.0.80.jar, /amqp/spring-rabbit/1.6.6.RELEASE/spring-rabbit-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar, /spring-messaging/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /amqp/spring-amqp/1.6.6.RELEASE/spring-amqp-1.6.6.RELEASE.jar, /spring-tx/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar, /retry/spring-retry/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/http-client/1.0.0.RELEASE/http-client-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/3.6.5/amqp-client-3.6.5.jar, /me/.m2/repository/com/company/thirdparty/generated/thing/thing-231/2.3.1/thing-231-2.3.1.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.7/groovy-all-2.4.7.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.0/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-test-junit/1.1.0/kotlin-test-junit-1.1.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-test/1.1.0/kotlin-test-1.1.0.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.0-groovy-2.4/spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar, /me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, /me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.8/logback-classic-1.1.8.jar, /me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.8/logback-core-1.1.8.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar, /me/.m2/repository/org/pitest/pitest/1.2.0/pitest-1.2.0.jar], mutators=[], dependencyAnalysisMaxDistance=-1, mutateStaticInitializers=false, jvmArgs=[], numberOfThreads=1, timeoutFactor=1.25, timeoutConstant=3000, targetTests=[^com\.company\..*$], loggingClasses=[], maxMutationsPerClass=-1, verbose=true, failWhenNoMutations=true, outputs=[HTML], groupConfig=TestGroupConfig [excludedGroups=[], includedGroups=[]], mutationUnitSize=0, shouldCreateTimestampedReports=true, detectInlinedCode=true, exportLineCoverage=false, mutationThreshold=0, coverageThreshold=0, mutationEngine=gregor, javaExecutable=null, includeLaunchClasspath=true, properties={}, maxSurvivors=0, excludedRunners=[]]
4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : System class path is /me/Applications/ActiveVersions/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 3641 mb
CP is :/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/common/lp-server-common-test/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-test-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/common/integrationtests/common-integrationtest/0.0.20/common-integrationtest-0.0.20.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/rest-assured/2.9.0/rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/2.4.7/groovy-xml-2.4.7.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/json-path/2.9.0/json-path-2.9.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/2.4.7/groovy-json-2.4.7.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/rest-assured-common/2.9.0/rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/restassured/xml-path/2.9.0/xml-path-2.9.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.3.0/jsonassert-1.3.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/json-path-2.2.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.2.1/json-smart-2.2.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.5/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.5/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.8.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.8.5/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.8.5/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.12/lombok-1.16.12.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/decision/lp-server-decision-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-decision-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/common/lp-server-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/annotations/pt-annotation-processors/1.0.3/pt-annotation-processors-1.0.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/annotations/pt-annotations/1.0.3/pt-annotations-1.0.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/utils/lombok-test-robot/1.0.1/lombok-test-robot-1.0.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/lp-server-common/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-common-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/server/read/lp-server-read/0.0.305-SNAPSHOT/lp-server-read-0.0.305-SNAPSHOT.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/calculator/pt-lp-calculator-core/0.0.13/pt-lp-calculator-core-0.0.13.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/company/platform/calculator/pt-lp-calculator-common/0.0.13/pt-lp-calculator-common-0.0.13.jar:/spring-context/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.6.1/springfox-swagger2-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.10/swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.10/swagger-models-1.5.10.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.6.1/springfox-spi-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.6.1/springfox-core-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.6.1/springfox-schema-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.6.1/springfox-swagger-common-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.6.1/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.0.0.Final/mapstruct-1.0.0.Final.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.6/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.6/tomcat-juli-8.5.6.jar:/spring-jdbc/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.5.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/me/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/me/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/enterprise/cdi-api/1.1/cdi-api-1.1.jar:/el/el-api/2.2/el-api-2.2.jar:/spec/javax/interceptor/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Beta1/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar:/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.5.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.5.Final.jar:/me/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.5.4/byte-buddy-1.5.4.jar:/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/data/spring-data-jpa/1.10.6.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:/data/spring-data-commons/1.12.6.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:/spring-orm/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/spring-aspects/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/spring-aop/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:/security/spring-security-config/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:/security/spring-security-web/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/axonframework/axon-test/3.0.2/axon-test-3.0.2.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/axonframework/axon-core/3.0.2/axon-core-3.0.2.jar:/me/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.9/xstream-1.4.9.jar:/me/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.4c/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/boot/spring-boot/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.6.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/me/.m2/repository/org/pitest/pitest/1.2.0/pitest-1.2.0.jar
4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : objc[28617]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java (0x10d7944c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10f7e94
4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : Sending 0 test classes to minion
4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : Checking environment

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : Expecting 0 tests classes from parent

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : Tests classes received

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : Found  0 tests

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : 0 tests received

4:52:46 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:52:46 PM PIT >> FINE : Running 0 units

4:52:47 PM PIT >> FINE : Coverage generator Minion exited ok
4:52:47 PM PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 0 seconds.
4:52:47 PM PIT >> FINE : Used memory after coverage calculation 47 mb
4:52:47 PM PIT >> FINE : Free Memory after coverage calculation 356 mb
4:52:47 PM PIT >> INFO : Created  0 mutation test units
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.113 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-31T16:52:47-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/404M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.2.0:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project lp-server-write: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.2.0:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
[ERROR] See http://pitest.org for more details.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Looking at the verbose output, you can see that the PITest Report Options include my directory as a location, but then in the classpath verbose output, there is no reference to my target directory. I don't know if this is why it can't find my tests, but it's definitely not the configuration. I have the widest params possible on my maven config `<targetClasses>com.company.*</targetClasses>` and `<targetTests>com.company.*</targetTests>`

Comment: I thought I had found the solution, but it still can't find tests. If it fails to find them once then everything is screwed and wiping my repo doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just had to wipe `pitest` from my maven repo. It repulled the jars and it worked. It seemed to have been holding onto settings, even when I had removed PITest entirely from my poms.

edit: apparently I'm an idiot. I had `mvn clean org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` which of course wipes my target directory before attempting to find the classes.